# UpdateCursor to insert DDM values from a layer in WGS84?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a layer in WGS84 (Geographic, DD) that I need to label in DDM (Degrees Decimal Minutes).

**I need to calculate within an arcpy UpDateCursor, a label field with DDM in it.**

I saw that you can run the [Convert Coordinate Notation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000tw000000), but I need to be able to calculate these labels on the fly within my cursor (this script is also [moving points around](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30597/how-to-simulate-moving-vehicles)).

After trapsing through the Esri forums I have not seen any snippets with how to achieve this.

This is likely a noob question, but this is very early steps for me any arcpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your points are in DD:

`import math`

```
def dd_to_ddm(val):
    minutes, degrees = math.modf(val)
    minutes = abs(minutes) * 60
        return "%i° %f'" % (degrees, minutes)
```